# Hide Shipping method from cart page in magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart, magento-1.9

I want to hide or remove the Shipping Method from cart page.
The reason to hide is we are giving free delivery on order above 15 pound.
but since magneto save the users shipping method in session it show the shipping and handling charge as 3 pound even though the order amount is greater than 15 pound (should be Free delivery).

Or way to unset shipping method from session.

Please refer the image.

[image: Remove shipping from Cart]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: While Magento would be an appropriate site, I would argue that the solution to this problem requires some degree of programming, be it investigation into the source that bubbles up to a configuration change or a programmatic solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the solution.

I have unset the current shipping method, using the following code snippets.

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote(); 
$shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
if($shippingMethod){
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod(null);  //setting method to null
    $quote->save(); 
}
```

Comment: If I put this code into template\checkout\cart.phtml , It will remove second refresh only.
For example: 
I added products into cart
Landing to cart page
Navigate to Check page
Enter billing, shipping, shipping method (amount added)
If I goto again cart page, i am seeing shipping amount in cart page
How to remove shipping item on cart page in first visit